# Display in viewport becomes orthographic

Tags: 3d-view, properties, world

Under World Properties, I added a Studio HDRI as an environment, and I suspect I must have messed with options within it.

It looks like this now (orthographic)[image]

This is what I want (Perspective)
[image]

How do I get it back to the default perspective view?

Comment: Press the '5' key on the numpad to toggle between perspective and orthographic views.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you, John, but I don't have the numpad keys. Do you know what else I can do?

Comment: On the View menu there's a Perspective/Orthographic entry to toggle betwen them or there are lots of YT videos on using Blender without a numpad since lots of people use laptops.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you. I've been able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Press the F3 button or click on the Grid Icon at the bottom of the Camera Icon
[image]